# Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError - Failed to install Atomic gem when creating new rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Here's the output after I ran `rails new blog` trying to create a new rails project, but I got this error every time at the installation of the Atomic gem part...

```
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Installing rake (10.1.0) 
Installing i18n (0.6.9) 
Installing minitest (4.7.5) 
Installing multi_json (1.8.2) 
Installing atomic (1.1.14) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby: invalid option -A  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/xxxxxx/Personal/Projects/RoR Apps/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/xxxxxx/Personal/Projects/RoR Apps/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'` succeeds before bundling.
```

---

My setup is running Mac OSX 10.9. I have installed xcode command line tool by `xcode-select --install`. Also installed Homebrew and RVM.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem today, since I recently installed Mavericks. It might be that you have a laundry list of things to update.

I updated XCode, the xcode-select -install, brew update, rvm requirement and gem update. After that atomic and the rest of my bundle install finally succeeded. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried all you suggested but seems I am still stuck at the same point. Could this be related to any libraries I need to install?